# Is there a way to extract QR code or Bar code from photo

Tags: php, android, ocr, zxing

I have a Google glass project in which i want to extract the contents of bar code and QR code by taking a picture of it from my Google Glass.

I was wondering is it even possible to determine the code from a photo ?. If yes then

Is there a free library for this. I am already using [zXing](https://github.com/zxing/zxing) for scanning QR code through camera but scanning a photo that has already been taken is a different.

I was also wondering, should i send the bar code photo to a webserver which could extract the contents of bar code from photo. Is there a library,script or piece of code that i can use on web server for extracting barcode from photo. 
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

You can try this [barcode online demo](http://www.dynamsoft.com/Demo/ICS/online_demo_scan_Barcode.aspx). Load a picture with barcode, and the barcode information will be displayed in the message box. (Load Image -> Try Barcode)